# MongoDB document : Is it ok to store array as associative array?

Tags: php, mongodb

For example, I have this document :

```
{
  "id": "kek",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "child1"
      "moreInfo":...
    },
    {
      "id": "child1",
      "moreInfo": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it ok to do :

```
{
      "id": "kek",
      "children": {
        "child1": {
          "id": "child1"
          "moreInfo":...
        },
        "child2:" {
          "id": "child2",
          "moreInfo": ...
        }
      }
    }
```

?

With this structure, in PHP it is easier to get the child we want :

```
$kek[children][child1]
```

Also, a child can have children too so it could looks like that :

```
$kek[children][child1][children][child3] ...
```

So we don't have to do recursive search.

But is it a good document structure in MongoDB's point of view ?

TY

Comment: One child has an unique parent yes.

Comment: @YRaito you can consider Array agains Documents approach. You can still search "children.0.children.3". With Array approach you can make an query like this "children.moreInfo.name" and then take back "all parents that has a child that is named Daniele". With Array you can use INDEX on "children.moreInfo.name". With your document-approach you can't do this because you must query for "children.child1" and "children.child2" and "children.child3" and so on until is end (and you don't know when the end came!). Even more, during UPDATE you don't know latest "child-N" then you can 'add' a new one eas

Comment: @Daniele Tassone I didn't think about indexes, you are right, so my "solution" is pretty bad :)